# If A: P implies Q and B: Q implies P, then A is the *what* of B?

Tags: logic, terminology

I have two propositions

```
A: P implies Q
B: Q implies P
```

is A then the *converse* of B, or is there a term that is more exact?

Comment: nope, converse is the correct term

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converse is the correct technical term here. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_(logic)